# PHP Upload file not showing on server

Tags: php, file-upload

I am writing a PHP to upload .PDF's to my server. Currently When I "upload" the file the system acts as if the task was completed, yet the file does not show up in the designated folder.

Form Code

```
<form id="add" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table><tr><td>
         <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" required />
    </td></tr><tr><td>
         <input id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </td></tr></tr></table></form>
```

PHP Code

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],"Flyers/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
```

Comment: have you checked write permissions for your app user ?

Comment: @danyel I'm still new to PHP, how would I do that?

Comment: As a note, you should never use the name provided by the user (`$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]`) as the actual file name on disk without careful filtering (e.g. only let through letters and digits). Like all user input, it should be treated as dangerous; e.g. it could be used to trick your application into overwriting a crucial file.

Comment: this might help you http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php

Comment: @IMSoP thank you for the tip, I will be sure to fix that once I get the upload to work :)

Comment: @danyel I appreciate your suggestion! I followed the directions within the link, but I'm still having the same problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you're trying to write to the folder that the script is running in but you need to give it a full path..

Try:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],"/Flyers/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

with a / before the Flyers and make sure there is a Flyers directory in the root of the server  eg. public_html/Flyers

and that it is writeable. (Your ftp client should give you some way of checking the permissions on a folder.)

Comment: I've already created the folder "Flyers", it is within the same folder as my script. I tried your suggestion but nothing seems to be happening.

Comment: perhaps just try uploading it to the root directory to see if we can pindown where the problem is: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

Comment: I'm getting the same results.

Comment: try echoing the results of the move eg: echo "Result = " . move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

Comment: You should get Result = 0 if the upload is failing and Result = 1 if it is succeeding

Comment: I tried this and once again my page just redirected back to the previous page. Normally the page is redirected back after processing the information, however I took out my redirect script and it still redirects anyways. Could this be a problem with my server?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is always a good idea to use absolute paths instead of relative paths as you may "get lost" with all the different files you may be using.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], __DIR__ . "/Flyers/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
```

`__DIR__` is the directory the script that contains this code resides in, change it accordingly

Secondly, you should check the return of `move_uploaded_file` to see if it was successful. This function returns a `boolean`, so if it was `true` then you know it was successful, otherwise somethine went wrong.

Usually it is folder permissions. If your webserver was not configured properly there maybe permission issues where the user that is running PHP does not have proper permissions to the folder and may be denied permission to write to that folder, which will break `move_uploaded_file`.

To solve this, you will need to fix your server config... which I will not cover here as there are too many variables that will affect this.
But you can try to set 777 or 775 permission to the folder you wish to upload to, either with your ftp software, ssh, or within php with `chmod` or `umask` (search them on PHP docs to see how to use)